# How to implement rewrite in nginx based on existence of a specific argument in the URI?

Tags: php, regex, redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

**Original Goal:** I wanted users trying to open page http://example.com/something to get redirected to http://example.com/index.php?download=something

**Original Goal Example:** 
Users coming to **Source URL**(http://something.com/18AhPyB&p=CdATyJnFMw1gl9Z) got redirected to **Destination URL**(http://something.com/index.php?download=18AhPyB&p=CdATyJnFMw1gl9Z)

**Things I did in my Nginx Config**:

```
location / {
rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?download=$1 last; }
```

**Problem With The Approach:** If someone is trying to open **homepage**(http://something.com) its giving error. My understanding is unintentionally I made all calls to get redirected.

**Question:** How I do make urls only with "&p" parameter to get redirected? Pl help.

Answer (score 0):

```
^\/(.*&p=.*)$
```

- ^ is the string start.
- \/ is the character */*  escaped.
- () the captured group.
- .* matches any character with unlimited length.
- &p= matches *&p=* literally.
- $ is the string end.

Regex101 ([here](https://regex101.com/r/dO0iQ8/2)) is great for creating and debugging regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you have to redirect only if the parameter **download** is present. Then yo have to write a location section like this:

```
index index.php;
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

    if ($arg_p) {
        return 301 http://something.com/index.php?download=$request_uri;
    }

    location = /index.php {

        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:6969;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Remember to change the port to your php-fpm or whatever yo use to process your php code.